# Debug Custom Server Socket Application

Tags: c#, sockets

I've been struggling to debug an issue with my C# socket application.  The application is part of a university assignment that I am working on.  The scope of the assignment is to build a webserver and game/application server using raw sockets.  In my case the webserver serves static files and acts as a proxy for the game server.  Serving files seems to be working well, but when forwarding requests through to the game server, there is a data transfer issue.

The complete [source code is available on GitHub](https://github.com/rossknudsen/TicTacToe) for reference.  But I think the problematic area is in [this area](https://github.com/rossknudsen/TicTacToe/blob/master/WebServer/Servers/WebServer.cs#L98) which tries to read the body of the response from the game server responding to the webserver's request.  Here is the relevant code:

```
if (header.ContainsKey("content-length"))
{
    var bodyLength = Convert.ToInt32(header["content-length"]);

    Console.WriteLine($"Receiving body from game server.  Expecting {bodyLength} bytes");
    body = ReceiveBodyData(socket, bodyLength);
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished receiving body from game server.  Received {body.Length} bytes.");
}
```

When it is executing this code the first message is written to the console, but the second message never prints because the method `ReceiveBodyData` never returns (ends up in an infinite loop trying to read the body data).

Examining the output from the game server, I see that the connection is closed from it's end, but I'm not sure if that kills the recipient's ability to read data or not.

Can anyone assist in debugging this issue, careful to recognise that this is *my* assignment, so ideally please don't write tons of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the issue.  I have [committed changes](https://github.com/rossknudsen/TicTacToe/commit/4b82ae1fc41322ae4ea81581a94d0454e2b058b9) that fix two bugs in my code.

## First bug

Sure enough, the `ReceiveBodyData` method had a logic flaw in it.  The method was as follows:

```
protected byte[] ReceiveBodyData(Socket handler, int bodyLength)
{
    // we know how many bytes to expect, so we create an appropriate array and keep track 
    // of how many bytes we've received.
    var result = new byte[bodyLength];
    var totalBytesReceived = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        // The bug is in the line below
        var bytesCount = handler.Receive(result, totalBytesReceived, bodyLength - totalBytesReceived, SocketFlags.None);

        if (totalBytesReceived >= bodyLength)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I was assigning the number of bytes read to a variable `bytesCount` but I wasn't updating the value of `totalBytesReceived` so I was never meeting the condition to exit the loop.

## Second bug

I don't quite understand why this bug occurs. Sometimes, after a valid connection is made and the request and response are exchanged, a second connection is created.  My code gets stuck because it is listening for the request data to be transmitted, but it never is, because it doesn't seem to be a valid connection.

I don't know if the browser is trying to maintain a persistent connection or quite what is going on here.  So I now return `null` if there is no data to receive.  The code that listens for connections, just goes back to listening.